# Dictionary to array conversion where dataframe does not produce correct row output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following data represent the lifetimes (in hours) of a sample of 40 transistors:

```
112, 121, 126, 108, 141, 104, 136, 134
121, 118, 143, 116, 108, 122, 127, 140
113, 117, 126, 130, 134, 120, 131, 133
118, 125, 151, 147, 137, 140, 132, 119
110, 124, 132, 152, 135, 130, 136, 128
```

Give a cumulative relative frequency plot of these data

My approach

1. First I create an array of the dataset
2. Then I find out the frequency of each number in the array
3. Then I create two lists to save the values of the data and their frequencies

My code:

```
LifeTime = [112, 121, 126, 108, 141, 104, 136, 134,
        121, 118, 143, 116, 108, 122, 127, 140,
        113, 117, 126, 130, 134, 120, 131, 133,
        118, 125, 151, 147, 137, 140, 132, 119,
        110, 124, 132, 152, 135, 130, 136, 128]
# initializing dict to store frequency of each element
dict_fre = {}
# iterating over the elements for frequency
for element in LifeTime:
  if element in dict_fre:
    dict_fre[element] += 1
  else:
    dict_fre[element] = 1
#code to store the keys and their corresponding values to the list
keys_list=[]
val_list=[]
for i,j in dict_fre.items():
keys_list.append(i)
val_list.append(j)
```

Next I create a dataframe using Pandas and save the keys_list and val_list as a dictionary so that I can calculate the relative frequency and then relative cumulative frequency. Then I will plot those data.

Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'life':[keys_list],'frequency':[val_list]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I got this output

```
                                      life                                     frequency
0   [112, 121, 126, 108, 141, 104, 136, 134, 118, ...   [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, ...
```

But I want to get something like that

```
life                                      frequency
112                                       1
121                                       2
126                                       2
108                                       2
```

How could I modify my code to get the desire output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
d = {'life':[keys_list],'frequency':[val_list]}
```

to this

```
d = {'life':keys_list,'frequency':val_list}
```

Your problem is by doing `[keys_list]` you effectively have one element in your list (of lists) and you get only one row.

Even better, you can directly set up your dataframe from your frequency dict.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_fre.items(), columns=['life', 'frequency'])
```

And to go beyond even better, use a function that Python provides to count the frequencies of an iterable.

```
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame(Counter(LifeTime).items(), columns=['life', 'frequency'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use data frame directly and then get the frequency for each value.

To convert your list to dataframe use the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_list,columns=['Column_Name'])
```

Then get the frequencies :

```
df["column_name"].value_counts()
```

Comment: I write the code `df = pd.DataFrame(keys_list,columns=['lifetimes'])
df = pd.DataFrame(val_list,columns=['frequency'])`. I got only frequency column. I want lifetimes and frequency both in the Dataframe

Comment: something like this ?
140    2
126    2
132    2
108    2
134    2
130    2
136    2
118    2
121    2